# User authenticate not passing rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rspec

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Learn Rails by Example Michael Hartli and am getting this error during rspec testing for authenticating the password. i think the other two errors are because of the first one. so just need a little help understanding whats going wrong and a solution.

```
Rays-MBP:sample_app raycove$ bundle exec rspec spec/
............F...............FF..

Failures:

  1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
       expected: #<User id: 6, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2016-02-19 21:45:28", updated_at: "2016-02-19 21:45:28", password_digest: "$2a$04$mweZJiYW0O/iDts7bCwUS.hb9GUznoH3nSGSeWdMHuW...">
            got: #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$juZNb6HH/yrXQUhYBd.tCeFqWYnwuQs2x.batWwMWhY..."> (using ==)
       Diff:


       @@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
       -#<User:0x007fa71611a4f8
       - id: 6,
       +#<User:0x007fa7161b0f70
       + id: nil,
         name: "Example User",
         email: "user@example.com",
       - created_at: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 21:45:28 UTC +00:00,
       - updated_at: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 21:45:28 UTC +00:00,
       + created_at: nil,
       + updated_at: nil,
         password_digest:
       -  "$2a$04$mweZJiYW0O/iDts7bCwUS.hb9GUznoH3nSGSeWdMHuWpxMMAV2W42">
       +  "$2a$04$juZNb6HH/yrXQUhYBd.tCeFqWYnwuQs2x.batWwMWhYJQtIAKvTou">
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:108:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.34838 seconds
32 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:108 # User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page 

Randomized with seed 13988
```

My user_pages_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end


  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end
end
```

My user_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
 password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end


describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters
    # is just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same
    # permit list between create and update. Also, you can specialize
    # this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    end
  has_secure_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true


end
```

I belive what is happening is when it runs through and gets to the   describe "return value of authenticate method" do section in user_spec
it changed the password or something as the passwords dont match but they are pre set so this cant be, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: in user_spec.rb try to replace `@user.save` with `@user.save!`. I suspect the save fails due to a failing validation.

Comment: Try replacing it ```{ should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }```

```it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }```

Comment: none of these have solved the issue